# SecurityAgent terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: exception, osx-lion

So far, three systems I manage have become unable to allow users to log on.  We use a PolicyBanner file (and have been doing so for months or years on dozens of Macs, and yes we've tried deleting /Library/Security/PolicyBanner.rtf from problem machines), and these systems get stuck there… hit the Accept button, and instead of being taken to a login screen, the system churns for a moment and returns them to the banner.  We've tried most or all of the usual suspects, and the only "solution" has been to restore an older Time Machine backup.

All three systems in question run 10.8.2  One is an iMac12,2, one is a MacBook Pro, and one is a bigger tower Mac (can't log in to it right now)  The only vague possibility I can come up with is, I'm a huge believer in doing as much from the command line as possible… I've scripted a number of things, including updating Java, Adobe Reader, MS Office, etc.  I suppose it's possible that installing one or more patches from the shell introduces some weird issue that 99.9% of Mac users would never see.  I have another MacBook Pro running 10.8.2 which has not manifested this issue, another macBook Pro running 10.7.5 that has not, and another older MacBook somewhere that I never see online or hear from the user :-)

Another data point... on systems with File Vault enabled, a user who boots the machine and unlocks the disk winds up being logged in.  They see the PolicyBanner, are prompted for their Apple ID, and then get a message about how there was some problem, do they want to open applications that were open before.  Once they're logged in, if they log out, the system is stuck at the banner again.

So, here's the system.log output.  Crash report put me over the 30K character limit but I'd be happy to provide it.

```
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: MacBuddy was run = 0
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:fraction:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc61222c40
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: NSExceptionHandler has recorded the following exception:
    NSInvalidArgumentException -- -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc61222c40
    Stack trace:  0x1057a5637  0x7fff8ac183f0  0x7fff8f0f06ea  0x7fff8f0485ce  0x7fff8f0483b8  0x7fff8b40ce8f  0x7fff90b521b4  0x7fff9109d18a  0x10594d919  0x10595c10e  0x7fff910a36cb  0x7fff910a1767  0x7fff910a141c  0x7fff8e3de29d  0x7fff8f052a46  0x7fff8e3ddfdd  0x7fff8e3de29d  0x7fff8f052a46  0x7fff8e3ddfdd  0x7fff8e468b75  0x7fff8e3de29d  0x7fff8f052a46  0x7fff8e3ddfdd  0x7fff8e3de29d  0x7fff8f052a46  0x7fff8e3ddfdd  0x7fff8e3de29d  0x7fff8f052a46  0x7fff8e3ddfdd  0x7fff8e3de29d  0x7fff8f052a46  0x7fff8e3ddfdd  0x7fff8e3dd634  0x7fff8e3a9a61  0x7fff8e533f44  0x7fff8e466b18  0x7fff8e466138  0x7fff8e465d1f  0x7fff9108d0c5  0x105959e50  0x105948a94  0x7fff8c879a2d  0x7fff8c8740b6  0x7fff8c8790c8  0x7fff8effc0fe  0x7fff8effb6b2  0x7fff8cae00a4  0x7fff8cadfe42  0x7fff8cadfcd3  0x7fff8e3a6613  0x7fff8e3a5ed2  0x7fff8e39d283  0x10577c544  0x7fff878ac7e1  0x1
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: An uncaught exception was raised
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc61222c40
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f05a0a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ac183f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f0f06ea -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f0485ce ___forwarding___ + 414
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f0483b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
        5   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff8b40ce8f CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData + 133
        6   LoginUICore                         0x00007fff90b521b4 LUICreateImageFromJPEGData + 12
        7   LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff9109d18a +[NSImage(LUIHelpers) imageForUserFromJPEGData:avatarType:] + 69
        8   loginwindow                         0x000000010594d919 APMechanismSetResult + 31889
        9   loginwindow                         0x000000010595c10e UserListOfUserWithPrimaryGroupGUID + 44376
        10  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff910a36cb -[LUIUserListViewController stripView:itemForColumn:] + 525
        11  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff910a1767 -[LUIStripView loadItemsForView] + 635
        12  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff910a141c -[LUIStripView viewWillDraw] + 160
        13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e468b75 -[NSScrollView viewWillDraw] + 45
        20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3dd634 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] + 1525
        33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3a9a61 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1044
        34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e533f44 -[NSNextStepFrame displayIfNeeded] + 84
        35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e466b18 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1377
        36  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e466138 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 940
        37  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e465d1f -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 159
        38  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff9108d0c5 -[LUIWindowController showWindow] + 498
        39  loginwindow                         0x0000000105959e50 UserListOfUserWithPrimaryGroupGUID + 35482
        40  loginwindow                         0x0000000105948a94 APMechanismSetResult + 11788
        41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c879a2d _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 77
        42  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c8740b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        43  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c8790c8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 275
        44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8effc0fe __CFRunLoopRun + 1614
        45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8effb6b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
        46  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cae00a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
        47  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cadfe42 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
        48  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cadfcd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
        49  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3a6613 _DPSNextEvent + 685
        50  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3a5ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
        51  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e39d283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
        52  SecurityAgent                       0x000000010577c544 SecurityAgent + 70980
        53  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff878ac7e1 start + 0
        54  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
    )
Feb 14 14:12:05 sahara SecurityAgent[1452]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc61222c40'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f05a0a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ac183f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f0f06ea -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f0485ce ___forwarding___ + 414
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f0483b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
        5   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff8b40ce8f CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData + 133
        6   LoginUICore                         0x00007fff90b521b4 LUICreateImageFromJPEGData + 12
        7   LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff9109d18a +[NSImage(LUIHelpers) imageForUserFromJPEGData:avatarType:] + 69
        8   loginwindow                         0x000000010594d919 APMechanismSetResult + 31889
        9   loginwindow                         0x000000010595c10e UserListOfUserWithPrimaryGroupGUID + 44376
        10  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff910a36cb -[LUIUserListViewController stripView:itemForColumn:] + 525
        11  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff910a1767 -[LUIStripView loadItemsForView] + 635
        12  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff910a141c -[LUIStripView viewWillDraw] + 160
        13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e468b75 -[NSScrollView viewWillDraw] + 45
        20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3de29d __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 + 307
        30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f052a46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
        31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3ddfdd -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 244
        32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3dd634 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] + 1525
        33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3a9a61 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1044
        34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e533f44 -[NSNextStepFrame displayIfNeeded] + 84
        35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e466b18 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1377
        36  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e466138 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 940
        37  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e465d1f -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 159
        38  LoginUIKit                          0x00007fff9108d0c5 -[LUIWindowController showWindow] + 498
        39  loginwindow                         0x0000000105959e50 UserListOfUserWithPrimaryGroupGUID + 35482
        40  loginwindow                         0x0000000105948a94 APMechanismSetResult + 11788
        41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c879a2d _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 77
        42  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c8740b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        43  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8c8790c8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 275
        44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8effc0fe __CFRunLoopRun + 1614
        45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8effb6b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
        46  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cae00a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
        47  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cadfe42 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
        48  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cadfcd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
        49  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3a6613 _DPSNextEvent + 685
        50  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e3a5ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
        51  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e39d283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
        52  SecurityAgent                       0x000000010577c544 SecurityAgent + 70980
        53  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff878ac7e1 start + 0
        54  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
    )
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: DebugSymbols was unable to start a spotlight query: spotlight is not responding or disabled.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: failed looking up LS service ( scCreateSystemService returned MACH_PORT_NULL, called from SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort, so using client-side NULL calls.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: LaunchServices/5123589: Unable to lookup coreservices session port for session 0x186a0 uid=0 euid=0
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Engine::authorize: Rule::evaluate returned 4294907288 returning errAuthorizationInternal
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara loginwindow[1440]: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara loginwindow[1440]: AuthorizationRef doesn't have a username (<LoginAuthRefMgr: 0x7f9e4c220640>). Exiting.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1441]: CGXRestartSessionWorkspace: session workspace exited for session 256 (on console)
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1441]: Session 256 released (1 references)
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1441]: Session 256 released (0 references)
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1441]: loginwindow connection closed; closing server.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.SecurityAgent.00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000186AC[1452]): Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara loginwindow[1493]: Login Window Application Started
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Server is starting up
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Session 256 released (1 references)
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: mux_initialize: Mode is dynamic
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: GLCompositor enabled for tile size [256 x 256]
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: CGXGLInitMipMap: mip map mode is on
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: true
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x04272d80: GL mask 0x11; bounds (0, 0)[1680 x 1050], 14 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9cb6, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x0000061000009cb60000000004272d80
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003f
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003e
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003d
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Created shield window 0x4 for display 0x04272d80
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Created shield window 0x5 for display 0x003f003f
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Created shield window 0x6 for display 0x003f003e
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Created shield window 0x7 for display 0x003f003d
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x04272d80: GL mask 0x11; bounds (0, 0)[1680 x 1050], 14 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9cb6, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x0000061000009cb60000000004272d80
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2704, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003f
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2705, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003e
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2706, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003d
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]:   Display 0x04272d80: MappedDisplay Unit 0; Alias(4, 0x11); Vendor 0x610 Model 0x9cb6 S/N 0 Dimensions 13.03 x 8.15; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1680 x 1050], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]:   Display 0x003f003f: MappedDisplay Unit 3; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2704,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]:   Display 0x003f003e: MappedDisplay Unit 2; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2705,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]:   Display 0x003f003d: MappedDisplay Unit 1; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2706,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: CGXMuxBoot: Boot normal
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022647, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003237, unit 0, caps QEX|QGL|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: Saved crash report for SecurityAgent[1452] version 7.0 (55116.8) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SecurityAgent_2013-02-14-141206_sahara.crash
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara ReportCrash[1492]: Removing excessive log: file://localhost/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SecurityAgent_2013-02-05-100201_sahara.crash
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022647, GL mask 0x0000000f, texture units 8, texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000010, accelerator 0x000048c7, unit 4, caps QEX|QGL|MIPMAP, vram 420 MB
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000010, texture units 8, texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara loginwindow[1493]: **DMPROXY** Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Created shield window 0x8 for display 0x04272d80
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x04272d80: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara launchctl[1496]: com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara com.apple.SecurityServer[20]: Session 100013 created
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara hidd[69]: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara hidd[69]: CGSDisplayServerShutdown: Detaching display subsystem from window server
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara helpd[1503]: Could not find access page in directory /Library/Documentation/Help/Norton Help Scripts
Feb 14 14:12:06 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara locationd[1505]: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x8000100 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara locationd[1505]: NOTICE,Location icon should now be in state 0
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara UserEventAgent[1500]: cannot find useragent 1102
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara loginwindow[1493]: Login Window Started Security Agent
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: 3891612: App SecurityAgent cannot order in untagged windows before login.
Feb 14 14:12:06 sahara WindowServer[1494]: kCGErrorInvalidOperation: CGXOrderWinsAndPanels: error ordering window
Feb 14 14:12:07 sahara com.apple.launchd.peruser.92[1406]: Background: Bug: 12C3012: launchd + 80370 [7DCC9489-2DF5-3807-83FA-EF5666EE8078]: 0x0
Feb 14 14:12:07 sahara com.apple.launchd.peruser.92[1406]: Background: This API can only be used by a process running within an Aqua session.
Feb 14 14:12:07 sahara SecurityAgent[1506]: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=5 label=[0x0-0x5a05a].com.apple.AppleSpell path=/System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/MacOS/AppleSpell flags=0
Feb 14 14:12:07 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 14 14:12:07 sahara SecurityAgent[1506]: Error launching spell checker for U.S. English:  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The application “AppleSpell.service” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred (OSStatus -10810)." UserInfo=0x7fc6d8c60940 {NSURL=file://localhost/System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/, NSLocalizedDescription=The application “AppleSpell.service” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred (OSStatus -10810)., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc6d8c62330 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10810.)"}
Feb 14 14:12:08 sahara WindowServer[1494]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 14 14:12:08 sahara WindowServer[1494]: Display 0x04272d80: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
Feb 14 14:12:09 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 14 14:12:09 sahara WindowServer[1494]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04272d80 device: 0x105604320  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
```